# NSXMLParser processing webpage

Tags: ios, iphone, nsxmlparser

I am using a website to find if a word exists or not in the romanian language. So i am creating an `NSXMLParser` with the following url: [http://dexonline.ro/definitie/caine](http://dexonline.ro/definitie/c%C3%A2ine.)

But the parser goes through the `<head>` element names and not through the `<body>` and i cant tell if the word was found.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    NSLog(@"%@",elementName);
}
```

The parser never reaches the body. What can i do ?

Comment: `NSXMLParser` is an XML parser and should be used for parsing XML, not HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSXMLParser` is probably not the correct tool for the job. It requires accurate XML input and often HTML from websites isn't accurate enough (missing tags / bad encoding / etc).

Instead, you may want to:

1. Find a different parser that is more free and easy about accuracy
2. Load into a web view and use javascript to find your content
3. Use `NSScanner` to locate and extract your content
4. Find a service which offers a proper API rather than trying to scrape the results

Comment: This answer was right, i used RayWenderlich solution to parse HTML and it was easier then i expected. http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios